# Suppose $ \phi : D_{6} \rightarrow C_3$ is a homomorphism, why are there 8 elements $g \in D_{6} $ such that $\phi(g)$ has order 3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to find all the homomorphic images of $D_{6}$

However, in the proof of $C_3$ is not a homomorphic image of $D_6$, the solution states that if such a $\phi $ exists with $C_3$ as its image, then there are 8 elements $g \in D_{6} $ such that $\phi(g)$ has order 3.

But $D_{6}$ only has 4 elements whose order is a multiple of 3, so $C_3$ is not a possible homomorphic image of $D_{6}$

Why is it the case that there are 8 elements $g \in D_{6} $ such that $\phi(g)$ has order 3?

Comment: Do you know a [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531889/using-counting-formula-to-get-g-kernel-%cf%86image-%cf%86) [relating](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955320/g-textorder-of-image-of-f-h?rq=1) the order of a group, a normal subgroup, and the quotient group?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, if $\phi $ : $G \rightarrow H $is a homomorphism, then |G| = |Im($\phi$)| |Ker($\phi$)|. I understand that this means that |Ker($\phi$)| = 4 here, but I'm not sure how that means there are 8 elements $g \in G$ such that $ \phi(g) $has order 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $y$ is in the image of $\phi$, then the number of solutions to $\phi(x) = y$ is equal to the number of elements in $\ker \phi$, and that there are two elements of $C_3$ with order $3$.

Now, verify that if $y$ has order $3$ and $x\in D_6$ satisfies $\phi(x) = y$, then $x$ must have order $3$.

Comment: Is the first part a common result / trivial? I had never seen that before.

Comment: @Shree it is very simple to show.  I don't know if it is a common result, though.  It is a natural conclusion to make if we consider the isomorphism between $D_6/\ker\phi$ and $C_3$ indicated by the first isomorphism theorem, though.  In particular, note that the elements solving $\phi(x) = y$ form one of the cosets in $D_6/\ker \phi$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that before, thanks for the explanation!